How to use Arm CMSIS-NN Softmax function for Embedded ML
I am trying to figure out how to use the CMSIS-NN Softmax function for a 16 bit signed input https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS-NN/blob/22080c68d040c98139e6cb1549473e3149735f4d/Source/SoftmaxFunctions/arm_softmax_s16.c.
Arm CMSIS-NN has provided an example input data and expected output data here (https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS-NN/tree/22080c68d040c98139e6cb1549473e3149735f4d/Tests/UnitTest/TestCases/TestData/softmax_s16) in their test case.
Initially, my first impression was that I couldn't use this out of the box, because when I look at the test cases config data (https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS-NN/blob/22080c68d040c98139e6cb1549473e3149735f4d/Tests/UnitTest/TestCases/TestData/softmax_s16/config_data.h), I see two config parameters softmax_s16_input_mult and softmax_s16_input_left_shift which I didn't really understand.
Furthermore, in the test case, it seems like they access an exponential look up table (https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS-NN/blob/22080c68d040c98139e6cb1549473e3149735f4d/Tests/UnitTest/TestCases/Common/Softmax/exp_lut_data.h) and a one by one look up table (https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS-NN/blob/22080c68d040c98139e6cb1549473e3149735f4d/Tests/UnitTest/TestCases/Common/Softmax/one_by_one_lut_data.h). I also looked into this (for example, the exponential look up table) which seems to be obtained by uniformly creating values from -10 to 0, and then, for each point, they compute e^x and scale it from [2^1 to (2^15)-1].
I did a bit more digging and I find here (https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS-NN/blob/22080c68d040c98139e6cb1549473e3149735f4d/Tests/UnitTest/softmax_settings.py) that the input_scale, which is used to generate the config parameters softmax_s16_input_mult and softmax_s16_input_left_shift, is a default parameter. So one question i'm curious about is, for my use case would I need to use a different softmax_s16_input_mult and softmax_s16_input_left_shift or can I just get away with using this "default" multiplier and shift provided.
For example, for my use case, I have a S16 bit input,
#include <stdint.h>
static const int16_t logits[15] = {2019, 4958, 1855, -230, -7992, 1396, -1919, 2611, 658, 3588, 885, -4759, 3426, 1348, 5906};

I assume, I need to generate my own exponential lookup table and one_by_one lookup table (i.e. one scaled from [-2^15 to (2^15) - 1]. For the exponential, I do so using this function below
def get_s16_exp_lut(input_range : list[int, int], num_vals : int, num_bits: int) -> np.array:
   """
   Takes in the specificed input range and the specified number of entries from CMSIS, 
   and computes the exponential of each point and scales it to num_bits range.                

  Example
  --------
  exp_lut = get_s16_exp_lut([-10, 0], 513, 16)
  """

  in_arr = np.linspace(input_range[0], input_range[1], num_vals)
  exp_in_arr = np.exp(in_arr)
  min_val = -2**(num_bits-1)
  max_val = 2**(num_bits - 1) - 1                
  normalised_exp = (exp_in_arr - np.min(exp_in_arr)) / (np.max(exp_in_arr) - np.min(exp_in_arr))
  scaled_exp = normalised_exp * (max_val - min_val) + min_val
  exp_lut_arr = np.round(scaled_exp).astype(np.int16)                
return exp_lut_arr

and I can easily modify this for the one_by_one case.
My main question is, can I get away with using the provided softmax_s16_input_mult and softmax_s16_input_left_shift or do I need to figure out the input left shift and multiplier for my case and, if so how would you suggest I go about doing so (if it helps, the example S16 bit input I shared above was obtained using this library). Whereby, after manually performing all the operations in each layer of my model, the final output (i.e. logits) is a fractional fixed point object that has a total of 16 bits, with 9 bits allocated to the fractional part of my data, 6 bits allocated to the integer, and 1 bit for the sign.
In general, am I right to say, for my use case, I'll need

A [-2^15, 2^15-1] exponential lookup table
A [-2^15, 2^15-1] one_by_one lookup table
Input Multiplier
Input Left shift

or can I get away with using the available input multiplier and input left shift?

If your goal is to get the classification, you don't need to softmax, you can just go from logits to classes.
